# Java constructors of classes

Tags: java, constructor

When I try to create a new instance of the class [`Point`](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/courses/software1/1011b/hw/04/API/Point.html)

```java
Point nir = new Point(double x, double y);
```

I'm getting the error

```
Multiple markers at this line
   - x cannot be resolved to a variable 
   - y cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How come? I want `x` and `y` to be general, not specific. I want to include my `Point` as a field of a new `class`.

EDIT:

In a given `class` named `Circle` I want to replace the fields `x0` and `y0`, that represent the coordinates of a point, with an object of type `Point`. So this is the begining of the class `Circle` that I want to refactor as above:

```java
public class Circle {

   private double x0, y0, radius;
```

So, I basically want to change the representation of `x0`, `y0` to `Point` structure.

Comment: can you show code, not javadoc?

Comment: Can you post the actual code  that is giving the error.

Comment: Please show us more relevant code

Comment: @Neal @Kevin @rlb.usa not necessary to solve the problem

Comment: Please read a basic Java tutorial, you are currently using Stack Overflow as your compiler.

Comment: @Bombe: Do you recommend on any stuff from the web? I tried to look for reference.

Comment: @Nir, there is this small, insignificant, unknown site by a company named “Google.” You should look it up on Altavista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting is that this code

```
new Point(double x, double y);
```

is not legal Java.  When you create an object or call a function, you do not specify the types of the arguments.  Instead, you just provide a value of that type.  So, for example, you could create a point by writing

```
Point origin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
```

Or

```
double x = 137.0;
double y = 2.71828;
Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
```

Because in both cases the compiler already knows the types of the expressions you're providing as constructor arguments.  You don't need to (and in fact should not) say that they're doubles.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Point nir= new Point(x, y);
```

If that doesn't work, show more code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the instance like so:

```
Point nir = new Point(x, y);
```

Or like so:

```
Point nir = new Point(15.0, 12.0);
```

where x and y are doubles. You're getting an error because you can't specify the type for arguments when calling a constructor, so `Point nir = new Point(double x, double y);` causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

x and y have to already made:

so do:

```
Point nir = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the parameters when it's expecting arguments. Try:

```
Point nir= new Point(x, y);
```

Or:

```
Point nir= new Point((double) x, (double) y);
```